# Openpyxl to create dataframe with sheet name and specific cell values?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

What I need to do:

- Open Excel Spreadsheet in Python/Pandas
- Create df with [name, balance]

Example:

| name | balance |
| --- | --- |
| Jones Ministry | 45,408.83 |
| Smith Ministry | 38,596.20 |
| Doe Ministry | 28,596.20 |

What I have done so far...

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as op
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from pathlib import Path
```

Then...

```
# Excel File
src_file = src_file = Path.cwd() / 'lm_balance.xlsx'

df = load_workbook(filename = src_file)
```

I viewed all the sheet names by...

```
df.sheetnames
```

And created a dataframe with the 'name' column

```
balance_df = pd.DataFrame(df.sheetnames)
```

My spreadsheet looks like this...

[image: sample spreadsheet]

I now need to loop thru each sheet and add the 'ending fund balance' and corresponding 'value'

- The "Ending Fund Balance" is at different rows, but always the final row.  The 'value' is always in column 'G'

How do I go about doing this?

I have read through examples in:

- Automate the Boring Stuff
- Openpyxl documentation
- PBPython.com examples
- Stack Overflow questions

I appreciate your help!

Working samples on github: [Github: JohnMillstead: Balance_Study](https://github.com/johnmillstead/balance_study)

Comment: not sure i understand what you want your final output to be. your example dataframe does not have the balance_value included

Comment: I first want to create the balance['name'] from the worksheet tabs -- which I did. Next is to create the balance['Ending Fund Balance'] from the value in the Excel sheet column 'G' in the row with "ending fund balance" as highlighted in yellow.  I can't use a row # because the "ending fund balance" can move up and down the row #'s depending on amount of data in a particular sheet.

Comment: Edit notes: Changed "ending fund balance" to "balance" to simplify things and changed the original dataframe to df.

Comment: mind sharing what you've done so far and the excel sheet? maybe dropbox or some other sharing service, if the data is not sensitive

Comment: @sammywemmy thanks! I'm about to knock-off for the evening.  I will create more dummy data and what I have done so far.  Thanks again!

Comment: @sammywemmy I created a sample spreadsheet and my humble .py beginnings.  You can access them on my github: https://github.com/johnmillstead/balance_study

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ge a cell value first set the `data_only=True` on `load_workbook`, otherwise you could end up getting the cell formula. To get last row of a worksheet you can use `ws.`[max_row](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.max_row). Combine the previous command with the already created dataframe and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for each worksheet name a function to get the last value from that worksheet at the `G` column (`wb[x][f'G{wb[x].max_row}']`).

```py
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

src_file = 'test_balance.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename = src_file, data_only=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=wb.sheetnames, columns=["name"])
df["balance"] = df.name.apply(lambda x: wb[x][f'G{wb[x].max_row}'].value)

print(df)
```

Output from *df*

```
                   name   balance
0        Jones Ministry  15100.08
1        Smith Ministry  45408.83
2        Stark Ministry   1561.75
3          Doe Ministry   7625.75
4       Bright Ministry   3078.30
5      Lincoln Ministry   6644.59
6     Martinez Ministry  11500.54
7       Patton Ministry   9782.65
8         Rich Ministry   8429.88
9        Seitz Ministry   2974.58
10       Bhiri Ministry    622.83
11  Pignatelli Ministry  34992.05
12      Cortez Ministry   -283.48
13      Little Ministry  13755.80
14     Johnson Ministry  -2035.31
```